# JavaScript Recursive Tree Searching Function Not Detecting Nested Children

Tags: javascript, recursion, tree, lint

Trying to make a recursive function that correctly searches the Tree class and all of its descendants for a value and returns true if that value is found, false otherwise.

Of particular importance is the recursive contains() function. Trying to get the code to pass the linter. I'm only getting one error about not detecting nested children. Everything else is passing.

My code:

```
/* eslint-disable no-trailing-spaces */
/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
class Tree {
  constructor(value) {
    this.value = value;
    this.children = [];
  }
  // Adds a new Tree node with the input value to the current Tree node 
  addChild(value) {
    this.children.push(new Tree(value));
  }
  // Checks this node's children to see if any of them matches the given value
  // Continues recursively until the value has been found or all of the children
  // have been checked
  contains(value) {
    const thisNode = this;
    function checkNode(node) {
      if (node.value === value) {
        return true;
      }
      if (node.children.length > 0) {
        for (let i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++) {
          return checkNode(node.children[i]);
        }
      }
      return false;
    }
    return checkNode(thisNode);
  }
}

module.exports = Tree;
```

Here is the file that tests it:

```
/* eslint-disable no-undef */
const Tree = require('../src/tree');

describe('Tree', () => {
  let tree;

  beforeEach(() => {
    tree = new Tree(true);
  });

  it('should have methods named "addChild" and "contains"', () => {
    expect(typeof tree.addChild).toBe('function');
    expect(typeof tree.contains).toBe('function');
  });

  it('should add children to the tree', () => {
    tree.addChild(5);
    expect(tree.children[0].value).toBe(5);
  });

  it('should return true for a value that the tree contains', () => {
    tree.addChild(5);
    expect(tree.contains(5)).toBe(true);
  });

  it('should return false for a value that was not added', () => {
    tree.addChild(5);
    expect(tree.contains(6)).toBe(false);
  });

  it('should be able to add children to a tree\'s child', () => {
    tree.addChild(5);
    tree.children[0].addChild(6);
    expect(tree.children[0].children[0].value).toBe(6);
  });

  it('should correctly detect nested children', () => {
    tree.addChild(5);
    tree.addChild(6);
    tree.children[0].addChild(7);
    tree.children[1].addChild(8);
    expect(tree.contains(7)).toBe(true);
    expect(tree.contains(8)).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

And here is the linting error:

```
Tree
    ✓ should have methods named "addChild" and "contains" (5ms)
    ✓ should add children to the tree (1ms)
    ✓ should return true for a value that the tree contains (3ms)
    ✓ should return false for a value that was not added (1ms)
    ✓ should be able to add children to a tree's child (1ms)
    ✕ should correctly detect nested children (9ms)
```

Comment: You are directly `return`ing from the `for` loop body. That means only the first iteration of the loop is executed. What do you actually want to do? Do you really want to return the result of checking the first child? Try to describe what you want to do before you write the code.

Comment: There are answers what's wrong with your code. Here a way how you can shorten/improve it: `const checkNode = node => node.value === value || node.children.some(checkNode);` and then `return checkNode(this);`

Comment: @FelixKling I just edited my description to 'Trying to make a recursive function that correctly searches the Tree class and all of its descendants for a value and returns true if that value is found, false otherwise.' Is that descriptive enough for you? Stack Overflow would be more profitable for all if it were a bit more gentle on newbies. End.

Comment: Sorry, I think it wasn't clear from my comment what the intention of it was.  I didn't mean to criticize your question, I'm trying to help you think about the problem. I meant that you should describe in words (to yourself or here or whatever), what you want to happen with the children. For example, I would describe it as "For every child, call checkNode. If the result is true, return true, else continue". Just be describing this idea, you might find the problem yourself.

Comment: @FelixKling I ultimately agree with you. I'm a noob and have been playing computer with paper and pencil beating my head against this problem for over 18 hours. Of some consolation to me is knowing that I was at least thinking in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You unconditionally return inside the for-loop, so you only check the first child.

```
    for (let i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++) {
      return checkNode(node.children[i]);
    }
```

Should be

```
    for (let i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++) {
      if (checkNode(node.children[i])) return true;
    }
```

Comment: You're 37 seconds faster than me :|

Comment: Fastest gun in the west :P

Comment: @Blorgbeard That worked. May the source always be with you, my friend.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is in this chunk of code here:

```
  if (node.children.length > 0) {
    for (let i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++) {
      return checkNode(node.children[i]);
    }
  }
```

This line of code will return from the function whatever the result of checkNode is for the first child, true or false. If the result is false you need to continue checking.

Try this instead:

```
  if (node.children.length > 0) {
    for (let i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++) {
      if (checkNode(node.children[i])) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think, this is what your code should look like:

```
for (let childIndex = 0; childIndex < node.children.length; childIndex++) {
   const foundInChildren = checkNode(node.children[childIndex]);
   if (foundInChildren)
     return true;
}
```